# how to do spark installation process on windows 8 environment

Tags: installation, apache-spark

I need to install spark 1.0.0 on my laptop, which has 64 bit OS windows 8, , java(java version "1.7.0_25"). I downloaded "spark-1.0.0-bin-hadoop2". But i don't know how to install spark 1.0.0. I also searched in Google but i can't find it properly. So can you please tell me the installation steps on windows 8 OS and what any other things are needed for this process ?

Comment: Daniel is correct about just using Linux rather than trying to do anything serious with Windows.  Windows is not OS for high-perf computing or Big Data, it's an OS for writing letters and playing games.

Answer (score 2):

You just extract the file you downloaded and you're good to go. You can now run `bin/spark-shell` to start experimenting.

If your cluster environment runs Linux though, I would recommend using Linux for experimentation/development as well. Having a matching environment will avoid a number of issues.

Answer (score 0):

Install **Java 7** or later. Set `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH variable` as environment variables.

> C:\java-version

Download **Scala 2.11** or **Scala 2.12** and install. Set `SCALA_HOME` and add `%SCALA_HOME%\bin` in PATH variable in environment variables.

To test whether Scala is installed or not, run following command in command prompt.

> C:\scala -version

Download and extract it to any drive i.e. **c:\program files\spark-1.2.1-bin-hadoop2.3.**

Set `SPARK_HOME` and add `%SPARK_HOME%\bin` in PATH in environment variables

Run following command on command prompt.

> C:\program files\spark-1.2.1-bin-hadoop2.3.\bin\spark-shell

Thats it. this is for windows OS.